Doxygen page titles are smaller than section titles?
I don't like that a page title in Doxygen uses a smaller font than a section title.
Can I define a page that still appears correctly in the Contents section (that is, the Contents entry is the page title), but when you look at that page you see a bigger font for the page title at the top than the section titles later in that page. Is there a way to do that?

Which version of doxygen are you using? Which output format are you using? Please give a small example!
